# How do I prove this graph is nonplanar?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

[image]

How do I prove this graph is nonplanar?
It has 11 vertices and 25 edges, with a girth of 3.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Kuratowski's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) says that a graph is nonplanar if and only if it contains either $K_5$ or $K_{3, 3}$ (or both).

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers

Comment: It is not a duplication of that problem there are a different number of vertices and edges in this graph.

Comment: The method in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2476186) solves the problem quickly.

Comment: Thanks, but I know the graph is non-planar, I'm just not sure how to write a proof of that

Comment: Why can't you write a proof using the Hamilton cycle argument?

Comment: how does a hamilton cycle prove non planar?

Comment: Read the answer that Misha linked.  Once you have found a Hamilton cycle in a graph, it's easy to determine whether or not it is planar.

Comment: I don’t think that’s a valid way to prove it though, just a way to check

Comment: Of course it's a valid way to prove it.  This is Tutte's theorem on conflict graphs.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533177/where-can-i%20-find-a-proof-of-tuttes-theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the center vertex and you're left with a graph $G$ that has $10$ vertices and $20$ edges. By Euler's formula, if $G$ were planar, it would need to have $12$ faces in any plane embedding.

Since $G$ has no triangles (all triangles of the original graph passed through the center vertex, which you can check), each face would have at least $4$ sides. This gives at least $48$ edges, counted twice; therefore $G$ would need to have at least $24$ edges. But $G$ has only $20$ edges, contradiction.

Comment: Also, by removing the $5$ inner edges of $G$, you get a subgraph which is a subdivision of $K_5$.

Comment: @bof You're right, but I'm personally really bad at finding minors and subdivisions, so I try to find other arguments whenever that's possible.